# Can a pilot still land if the tower gives confusing Information?

Tags: safety, air-traffic-control, landing, radio-communications

Recently an [airplane crashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US-Bangla_Airlines_Flight_211) at Kathmandu airport in Nepal. The people that owned that plane claim that confusing information was given to the pilot by the control tower, and as a result the plane crashed. Conversation between pilot and control tower [given here](https://youtu.be/nQML3G26COQ).

Now my question is: if confusing directions are given by the control tower, what should a pilot do? Should they wait for the exact decision and continue flying, or can they decide to make the plane land safely?

Comment: Pilot's prerogative is they can do anything they deem necessary to keep the craft and it's passengers safe. So to answer your question, "can they decide to make the plane land safely", yes, regardless of the rest of your question.

Comment: Please clear me which part of my question suffering you guys to give an exact answer ?

Comment: Not sure why people are VTC. It seems a reasonable question. But the answer is fairly simple: ask them to clarify. Not sure of the regs in Nepal, but unless there's an emergency, at a controlled airport they shouldn't land unless they hear the words "cleared to land, runway XX." If there's any doubt they should ask.

Comment: No one in the tower or air traffic control is responsible for the lives and safety of the people on your aircraft but you, the pilot in command. That's why it's called "command". He/she is responsible, and will take the blame (or the credit) for the consequences of the decisions made and the actions taken.  Yes there are rules, and if you violate them, you will probably have to explain why, but you will need a bigger better explanation if you follow the rules and people die as a result.

Answer (score 7):

At or near touchdown on the runway? Ignore it. The last thing any pilot should do in the critical period near runway touchdown is try to determine what a confusing or unclear radio transmission actually meant.

On the other hand, if "at the time of landing" includes two minutes prior to touchdown, up on downwind, or 4  nm out on extended final approach, different story.

What the cutoff is between these two extremes is what we pay pilots for. It's called situation awareness and exercise of good judgment.

Comment: If I heard my call sign at or near touchdown I'd probably go around before I even heard the rest of the transmission.

Comment: November upmty ump, Garble Garble, ... on fire! ... garble garble....

Comment: More likely, "November xxxx, gear up!" or "November xxxx, runway incursion!"

Comment: More likely? who cares what's more likely. Without complete or accurate information, you would make critical decisions on what in your opinion is more likely?  What does your overall situation awareness tell you? What's your fuel state? how hard was this approach? What is the weather like? If you don't KNOW what a radio transmission actually meant, then your own SA and judgment is should take precedence over any assumptions about what might be more likely, .... unless you don't have any ...

Comment: If somebody is calling me short final or later, it better be because there's an imminent hazard to landing. If I'm on fire, shut up and roll the trucks.

Comment: Well, I guess for someone who is pre-loaded to take specific action X, then I guess everyone else should of course only initiate those communications/actions which would make reaction X appropriate...  AFAIK, that is not in the FAA "Expected pilot Reactions to unclear communications" policy.  We make clearing turns to the left first, because the standard is to pass on the right when overtaking. There is no such standard as to what to do when receiving an unclear transmission. It is (and should be) up to the pilots Situation awareness and judgment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75519/discussion-between-charles-bretana-and-fred-larson).

Answer (score 5):

If there is a doubt, there’s no doubt: 
GO AROUND.

Comment: While this may be good advice this answer could be improved by explaining the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Question is clear . What reasons I need to add please mention.

Comment: @user70421 you should comment under your question not under an answer, nobody will see this.